# Emma to instrument a WAR file

Tags: war, emma

I have to test the code coverage of web services hosted on Tomcat during Unit Testing. I'll be doing manual testing means i'll pass different values of parameters in my http request and need to have a coverage report for each test case means for each request sent to the server. How can i do that with Emma or is there any other tool that I can use?

or

Please tell the steps to instrument WAR using Emma

Answer (score 0):

1. create an ANT target in your project which does a compilation of the source code and instruments the class files and create war file.
2. Copy the emma-2.1.5320.jar jar to java/jre/lib/ext/ directory(whichever java your tomcat uses).
3. create a setenv.sh file in tomcat/bin/ directory which contains below lines:

   ## !/bin/sh

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Demma.coverage.out.merge=true"

4. restart tomcat server and check if the above properties are updated in tomcat process (ps -aef | grep tomcat)
5. Then copy this generated war file to the tomcat/webapps/ directory.
6. start your test cases and now you should see the below line in your catalina.out file
   EMMA: collecting runtime coverage data